# Why is $E1_{(|X| \ge \epsilon)} \le \epsilon^{-p} E|X|^p 1_{ (|X| \ge \epsilon)}$

Tags: probability

This is from a proof in my book.

$$E1_{(|X| \ge \epsilon)} \le \epsilon^{-p} E|X|^p 1_{ (|X| \ge \epsilon)}$$

If $|X| < \epsilon$, then the right hand side is 0, since the indicator function is 0, and the other stuff are just constant. But the left hand side is not equal to 0 (only for some random variables, not all). So the equation seems to be wrong?

It is correct if it it was instead $$E1_{(|X| \ge \epsilon)} \le \epsilon^{-p} E \left(|X|^p 1_{ (|X| \ge \epsilon)}\right)$$

Comment: The RHS is meant to be $\epsilon^{-p} E \left(|X|^p 1_{ (|X| \ge \epsilon)}\right)$. Unfortunately it's very common to leave out brackets like that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your book is not very explicit on where expectation starts and ends. Here is my attempt:

$$|X|\cdot 1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}} \ge\epsilon\cdot 1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}$$

raising to the $p$th power:

$$|X|^p\cdot1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}\ge\epsilon^p\cdot 1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}$$

Then take the expectation both sides:

$$E[|X|^p\cdot1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}]\ge\epsilon^p\cdot E[1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}]$$

which is what you want.

If you leave $1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}$ out of the expectation on the RHS, then as you said, you have a r.v. on the RHS and a constant on the LHS, and the inequality should happen for all points in the sample space, which is not the case.

Usually I disambiguate using the context (which book is it and how the inequality is used in the proof?). However, if the book keeps on being ambiguous, you may consider another book altogether.

Comment: The context is most likely the proof of Markov's inequality.

Comment: I've been thinking the same thing, except that Markov doesn't need indicator functions on both sides, $|X|\ge\epsilon\cdot 1_{\{|X|\ge\epsilon\}}$ is sufficient. This is slightly stronger.

Comment: $P(|X| \geq \epsilon) = E \left[1_{\{|X| \geq \epsilon\}}\right]\leq E\left[|X|^p/\epsilon^p 1_{\{|X| \geq \epsilon\}}\right] \leq E\left[|X|^p\right]/\epsilon^p$

The first inequality is the one OP cites.